# Is there any way to get absolute positioning in CSS to be based off the entire page instead of the viewable window?

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-position

I currently have an HTML page running a full screen canvas element. In this canvas element, I have various things drawing that fill up the page. As the page is resized, the things drawn are adjusted in size in order to fill the screen. However, once a certain minimum size is reached, the things drawn are no longer adjusted, and instead, I add overflow scrollbars to the page.

Right now, I'm trying to add a new element over the canvas that is permanently fixed to a position relative to the bottom right corner of the canvas. Giving the div a css styling of `postion:absolute;` works fine while the canvas is rescaling. However, as soon as the page crosses that minimum size and the canvas no longer rescales, and instead scroll bars appear, the new div keeps moving with the viewable window, instead of staying where it should be relative to the canvas. I've played around with using `postion:fixed;` (replacing the css with jquery) once the size is small enough, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Best,
Sami

Comment: Can you make a div position:relative to a canvas?

Comment: Can you recreate a small example on jsfiddle.net for reference?

Comment: @jimw - no you can't. anything within a canvas is displayed solely if the browser is incapable of dealing with canvas elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

contain the canvas in a container div i.e

```
<div class="canvas_container">
    <canvas></canvas>
    <div class="positioned_element"></div>
</div>
```

and in your CSS

```
.canvas_container{position:relative;}
.positioned_element{position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;}
```

This will make the positioned element go to the right/bottom of the parent ".canvas_container" and not the body of the site.

Comment: i've done this though and it doesn't work... using "bottom" with any positive value makes the div i'm trying to position go outside of the window, implying that the div it is underneath is entirely above the canvas. i've only debugged this using google chrome's javascript dev tools, so i don't know if this is a chrome specific issue, and if this will work with other browsers. i guess i should try that...

Comment: no it doesn't work for me in firefox either. moving the left part of the window past the minimum size will make the new div move along with it.

Comment: You'll have to set the width and height of the container. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mq9x8/4/ **EDIT**: Updated it.

Comment: sweet thanks for that - width and height seems to have fixed it